# C# class property getting cached?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, class, asp.net-4.5

I have a class and am setting a UID as a class property because it is used in many methods throughout the program and I don't want to keep having to pass in a value to it. The issue I'm getting is that when I run `context.Response.Write(uid)` and refresh the page, I get the same value every time.

If I move `createRandomString()` to `context.Response.Write(createRandomString())`, I get a new UID every time I reload.

I'm very new to using C# and coming from a PHP background, this is a bit odd for me. I would think that setting a class property would change every load. I'm thinking it probably has something to do with when the program is compiled, the UID is permanently set which still wouldn't make sense.

Code where property is getting set:

```
public class Emailer : IHttpHandler {
    // Define UID
    static string uid = createRandomString();
```

CreateRandomString Code:

```
public static string createRandomString() {
    Guid g = Guid.NewGuid();
    string GuidString = Convert.ToBase64String(g.ToByteArray());
    GuidString = GuidString.Replace("=", "");
    GuidString = GuidString.Replace("+", "");

    return GuidString;
}
```

Comment: you uid property is a static property and therefore only loaded once and not refreshed when accessed again.

Comment: @invalidusername It's one of those days... I don't get how it's not getting reset though every time the page is reloaded. Does it just get set once upon compilation like I thought?

Comment: In addition this means your field (not a property though) is just intialized, when your class is referenced the very first time by using any of its members or when the class is instantaited the very first time. This usually happens once and only once.

Comment: what @HimBromBeere is saying.. and yes, field, not property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by keeping the fields static but setting the value upon load.

Fields:

```
// Define UID
static string uid = "";

// Define upload path for files
static string uploadPath = "";
```

Setting:

```
// Define UID
uid = createRandomString();
uploadPath = @"c:\" + uid + @"\";
```

Comment: Why do you think you need the members to be `static`? From what you described I bet they shouldn´t.

Answer (score 0):

Static fields are only instansiated once.  That is why you always get the same result.  Try this...

```
public class Emailer : IHttpHandler
{
    // Define UID
    string uid => createRandomString();
}
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645751(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: I'm setting my upload path as another field using the uid. Both are static, what can I do here?

Comment: Stop using static unless it is appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Static class level members with an initialiser are only once the first time any memeber of the class (static or otherwise) is referenced.

The initialisation will only re-run when the assembly the class is contained in is unloaded from memory (e.g. when then executable is unloaded).

For an ASP application the assemblies are loaded and unloaded by the IIS process so you would fund that if you restarted the IIS process (for example) this would cause a new UID to be generated.

Comment: Is there anyway to force it to reset with every load?

Comment: @JoeScotto by not making it static

Comment: @JoeScotto or by making it a method not a property/field for example - public static Guid GetNewOne() { return Guid.NewGuid(); }

Comment: @SpaceUser7448 That depends on if multiple accesses to it in a single request should get different values or the same value.